# Why does Jest try to resolve every component in my index.ts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

So I'm using Jest (with Enzyme) to test a Typescript-React project, and am having an issue with an alias module.

I know the problem per se isn't finding the module, because it finds the module correctly. I think the problem may be the structure of one of my files.

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "collectCoverage": false,
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "!**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  ],
  "coverageDirectory": "test",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
  ],
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testURL": "http://localhost",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$"
  ],
  "resolver": "jest-webpack-resolver",
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
    "^components$": "<rootDir>/src/components",
    "^reducers$": "<rootDir>/src/reducers",
    "^actions$": "<rootDir>/src/actions",
    "^selectors$": "<rootDir>/src/selectors",
    "^services$": "<rootDir>/src/services",
    "^views$": "<rootDir>/src/views",
    "^domains$": "<rootDir>/src/domains"
  },
};
```

Import used in my component being tested:

```
import { Label } from 'components';
```

My project structure leads the following way in components:

```
src
  |_ components
   |_ // ..various folders with React components
   |_ index.ts
```

And my index.tsx basically looks like this:

```
export { default as Label } from './Label/Label'
// export other components
```

What's happening is the following:

When I run Jest, it resolves my 'components' module fine, it's the same in my webpack.alias, but what is breaking the test run is that it starts to 'build' (I'm not sure if it actually builds?) other components, and starts going up the dependency tree for some components I'm not even testing, and eventually breaks because it goes all the way up to my main index.tsx file that runs the entire app.

Is the problem the way I've structured my index.ts to export all my components?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems to be related to jest having it's own module resolver. Maybe this helps: https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules